# Spring Boot + Flyway + Gradle + Yaml app not generating DB on startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, yaml, flyway

I have an app that uses Spring Boot app and I want to add a DB migration with flyway to it but for some reason is not working.

In my gradle file I have added this dependency:

```
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
```

Then in my yml configuration file, I add the following:

```
spring:
  flyway.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database
  flyway.user: postgres
  flyway.password: postgres
```

In addition to this, I have my .sql scripts under resources/db/migration.
They have the right naming format(V1__base.sql).

I run the app using ***gradle bootrun***

According to the documentation that I am following, this should just work out of the box. My database is running locally in a docker container and I don't see any error in the terminal. What am I missing?

The instructions I am following are from here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot

Comment: Please check log file there has to be error else it should work fine.

Comment: You might forgot to mention dialect class in configuration file.

Comment: @iamrajshah I am running using --debug and I dodn't see any ERROR. I didn't see in the documentation that is mandatory to set any dialect. Do you know where can I find that information?

Comment: @babylonian, which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: @codemonkey I am using `2.0.2.RELEASE`